# download more than 4000 Contacts details from Salesforce.com to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to download more than 4000 contacts from Salesforce.com. I go through all the API available for iPhone/iPad development. I use the zkSforce Classes provided for the iPhone/iPad application development. Still i didn't find any proper solution for the same.So guys please help me out.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I want to download 4000 contacts but it is not possible to download at the same time. I think in first time i should download 1000 contacts details, now second time i should download contacts from 1000 to 2000. like wise i want to download the contacts.

Comment: So is there any way to download batch wise ?

Comment: I use the Query() function which is used to download contacts. But it has limitation like you can not download more than 200 contacts.

Comment: According to me you have to send your udid of iphone for access the webservice to fetch the contact when its goes first time then your webservice decide which contact have to send or you can send value in webservice to get the contacts between these value

Comment: I use the zkSforce Classes. I am doing same thing. I log in using my Salesforce.com Username and Password.I am able to download 1000 contacts, now i want to download another 2000 Contacts. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `queryMore` method on `ZKForceClient`, first run `query` and the returned `ZKQueryResult` object will contain your first 1000 records, and if there are more than that on Salesforce it will contain a `BOOL` set to `NO`, the BOOL is named `done`, check that condition, if it is `NO` then there will be an `NSString` in `queryLocator`. You will use this string to pass to `queryMore` which also returns a `ZKQueryResult` object that you can use to repeat this pattern.

For info on queryLocator check out the documentation, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_querymore_querylocator.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think You can not use QueryMore to download the next 1000 Contacts. See this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm#topic-title. QueryMore retrieve the remaining contacts from Query.

Comment: Flash i explain you my Problem in detail.

Comment: I have 5000 Contacts on Salesforce.com. Now when i use Query i get 1000 Contacts. QueryMore is use to retrieve next batch of record from Query but i already had those records. Now i want to retrieve next 1000 Records from Salesforce.com Like wise i want to download all the Contacts.

Comment: Raxit, I have done the exact thing you are trying to do using this method. queryMore/queryLocator gives you the next 1000 records just like you need.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce is providing mobile SDK using REST.

Check this following link, that helps you where to start with.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154863/299662