# How to integrate Salesforce in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

can any one help me in integrating salesforce in my app.I have made account in sales force and also created the remote-acces key.Can anyone tell how to ad objects ,dashboards etc in the iPhone app.I also want to know how to access the data on salesforce .for e.g. i want to get all the custom objects in salesforce and also want to create custom objects from iPhone app.Can anyone guide me in this respect.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. I advice you to read carefully and choose the best way to do it.

Here are some links to read about it:

[Making Salesforce and PayPal Work Together](http://www3.formassembly.com/blog/doc/connectors/salesforce/advanced-integration/making-salesforce-and-paypal-work-together/)

[SDK Project](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS)

[Good Documentation and code](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK)

Comment: sorry but that all what i can do :(
but if the native help u it is good for u :)

Comment: ..thanks for the help and your suggestion.                                     The link you suggested is for hybrid app and i want to follow native app .I am able to retrieve the data using query and hen making request.But the problem is that i am not able to get all custom objects list and dashboard setting.I have downloaded the code from git-hub also but that also not working .Is there any way to get the view after login to similar to that in our salesforce accounts and how to add different tabs in i-Phone for different options like objects ,dashboard etc.

Comment: ca you tell me what is the main difference between hybrid and native app .And which is the best to use..

Comment: look at this table http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/comparey.png/

u can say 90% of what written true and relative to mobile app

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce provides mobiles SDK for iPhone, Android & hybrid platforms.
This SDK has samples on how to start with. There are lot of documentations available.

Basically the SDK helps to authenticate with Salesforce using oAuth, communicating with the objects using RestKit.

Refer the following URLs to start with..

Download the mobile SDK from the following URL.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS

There is a discussion forum
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Mobile/bd-p/mobile

API docs
http://forcedotcom.github.com/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/Documentation/SalesforceSDK/index.html

Ref: 
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK